# IndexOfObject return 2147483647

Tags: iphone, nsarray, nsrangeexception

I have an array with 10 items. When I call "`IndexOfObject`" for the elements number 9 and the element number 10 Xcode return an exception: "`NSRangeException`"

> reason: '_[_NSCFArray objectAtIndex:] index:2147483647 beyond
>   bounds(10)'.

From a previous `NSLog`, I saw that the two elements exist in the array but `indexOfObject` not find them. Why?

My code is:

```
    NSDictionary * headConfig =[avatarDictionaryToSave objectForKey:@"head_dictionary"];
    NSString * headImage =[headConfig objectForKey:@"layer_key"];
    NSString * pathFace =[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Face" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSLog(@"%@", headImage);

    NSArray *arrayFace =[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:pathFace];
    NSLog(@"the  elements are: %@", arrayFace);//here headImage is present
    int index =[arrayFace indexOfObject:headImage];
    NSLog(@"the index is %d", index);
```

Comment: How you are retrieving index?

Comment: It seems you are confusing between `indexOfObject` and `objectAtIndex`? The former will find the object, while the latter retrieve the object at index in the array?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`indexOfObject:` returns `NSNotFound` when the object is not present in the array. `NSNotFound` is defined as `NSIntegerMax` (== 2147483647 on iOS 32 bit).

So it seems that the object you are looking for is just not there.

Comment: Or on 64 bit architecture, returning 9223372036854775807.

Answer (score 0):

```
     Please change the coding of adding the array values as I mentioned below.
    //  [arr_values addObject:[dictionary valueForKey:@"Name"]];
     [arr_values addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dictionary valueForKey:@"Name"]]];

   When target array elements are not in string format then while we using the 
indexOfObject then that value can't able to find in the target array. So please try to 
change the value of object as mentioned above while adding into array.
```

Comment: For your information this is also one of the failure for one case. I have faced the same case so I have answered here. If you try some other solutions still not able to find solution then try this too.

Answer (score -1):

By default, an integer is assumed to be signed.

In other words the compiler assumes that an integer variable will be called upon to store either a negative or positive number. This limits the extent that the range can reach in either direction.

For example, a 32-bit int has a range of `4,294,967,295`. In practice, because the value could be positive or negative the range is actually `−2,147,483,648` to `+2,147,483,647`.

If we know that a variable will never be called upon to store a negative value, we can declare it as unsigned, thereby extending the (positive) range to `0` to `+4,294,967,295`.

An unsigned int is specified as follows:

```
unsigned int myint;
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.